# Gzip compression of files in an umbraco solution

Tags: .net-4.0, gzip, umbraco, client-dependency

I have an Umbraco 4.7.x project (.NET 4.0 webforms) where I want to compress all html/css/js.  Heres what ive done so far:

I have the newest `ClientDependency.Core.dll` and `Umbraco4.ClientDependency.dll` in my bin folder and registered in my web-config.

I've updated `ClientDependency.config` (from http://clientdependency.codeplex.com/releases/view/72284#DownloadId=273765)

I have compression enabled in my web-config:
`<urlCompression doDynamicCompression="true" doStaticCompression="true" dynamicCompressionBeforeCache="true"/>`

Am i missing something, in order to get this to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you have the dynamic compression module installed?

http://blog.wassupy.com/2009/08/enabling-dynamic-http-compression-in.html

Comment: Hmm interesting. Im pretty sure I have IIS7.5, and it would be surprising if it isnt installed. I will look into it and get back.

Comment: I've always had to install it.